# Left join error in dplyr in R- Must share the same SRC

Tags: r, csv, dplyr, left-join, union

I am trying to left join a ds I created through `union` function in R. The function `union` seems to be stacking my 2 datasets properly. However when I try to left join it with one of the datasets stacked via union, I get the following error:

```
Error in `auto_copy()`:
! `x` and `y` must share the same src.
ℹ set `copy` = TRUE (may be slow).
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

The following is my R code:

```
union_02 <- union(ds_x, ds_y)

ds_prop <- ds_get_prop |>
  dplyr::left_join(union_02, by = "Prop_No")
```

I also converted the object `union_02` into a data-frame using the following code:

```
ds_union <- data.frame(union_02)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 2292, 1796
```

Why do differing number of rows matter in an object that have been stacked onto one another using `union`?

Anyways how do I make the left join happen?

Thanks

Comment: How are `ds_x`  and `ds_y` defined? This suggests they are not (yet) in-memory objects, perhaps SQL, arrow, or something else data-lazy?

Comment: @r2evans I am working on ```R``` and have not used ```SQL``` at any point. Both ```ds_x``` and ```ds_y``` are created out of .csv files imported into R via path indicating to local directory on my laptop. However these two .csvs are stored in different sub folders.

Comment: Okay. I don't think this is reproducible at the moment. Can you create two small samples (perhaps `head(x,3)` or 4 for each frame) that still reproduces your error, and then post those samples with `dput(..)` in your question?